# What is the difference between specifying the transport parameter of turn's url as udp and not specifying any parameter?

Tags: webrtc, turn

I always thought that if you configure url1=`turn:a.com`, then it is compatible with udp and tcp, meaning that you use udp to try first, and then switch to tcp to try if you can't connect to the turn server.

But I tried it on Chrome 114.0.5735.90 for Mac OS (x86_64) and found that using url1 will only try udp, not tcp at all.

This means that url1 and url2 have exactly the same effect.

I know to configure two urls to try both udp and tcp::

```
urls=["turn:a.com?transpsport=udp", "turn:a.com?transport=tcp"]
```

But I want to use a url that can try udp first and then try tcp if it doesn't work. is there such a configuration?